# Rewrite Invoice Model

Tags: magento

Can someone help me overwriting a model in Magento.
Somehow i get it not done.

I have the following code's

local/WP/Mstock/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <WP_Mstock>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </WP_Mstock>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <sales>
              <rewrite>
                  <order_invoice>WP_Mstock_Model_Order_Invoice</order_invoice>
              </rewrite>
          </sales>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

local/WP/Mstock/Model/Invoice.php

```
<?php
class WP_Mstock_Model_Order_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice
{

    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->getId()) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cannot register existing invoice'));
        }

        foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getQty()>0) {
                $quantity = $item->getQty(); 
                $product_id = $item->getProductId();
                $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product_id);
                $stock->setQty($stock->getQty()-$quantity);           
                $stock->save();
                $item->register();
            }
            else {
                $item->isDeleted(true);
            }
        }

        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $captureCase = $this->getRequestedCaptureCase();
        if ($this->canCapture()) {
            if ($captureCase) {
                if ($captureCase == self::CAPTURE_ONLINE) {
                    $this->capture();
                }
                elseif ($captureCase == self::CAPTURE_OFFLINE) {
                    $this->setCanVoidFlag(false);
                    $this->pay();
                }
            }
        } elseif(!$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->isGateway() || $captureCase == self::CAPTURE_OFFLINE) {
            if (!$order->getPayment()->getIsTransactionPending()) {
                $this->setCanVoidFlag(false);
                $this->pay();
            }
        }

        $order->setTotalInvoiced($order->getTotalInvoiced() + $this->getGrandTotal());
        $order->setBaseTotalInvoiced($order->getBaseTotalInvoiced() + $this->getBaseGrandTotal());

        $order->setSubtotalInvoiced($order->getSubtotalInvoiced() + $this->getSubtotal());
        $order->setBaseSubtotalInvoiced($order->getBaseSubtotalInvoiced() + $this->getBaseSubtotal());

        $order->setTaxInvoiced($order->getTaxInvoiced() + $this->getTaxAmount());
        $order->setBaseTaxInvoiced($order->getBaseTaxInvoiced() + $this->getBaseTaxAmount());

        $order->setHiddenTaxInvoiced($order->getHiddenTaxInvoiced() + $this->getHiddenTaxAmount());
        $order->setBaseHiddenTaxInvoiced($order->getBaseHiddenTaxInvoiced() + $this->getBaseHiddenTaxAmount());

        $order->setShippingTaxInvoiced($order->getShippingTaxInvoiced() + $this->getShippingTaxAmount());
        $order->setBaseShippingTaxInvoiced($order->getBaseShippingTaxInvoiced() + $this->getBaseShippingTaxAmount());


        $order->setShippingInvoiced($order->getShippingInvoiced() + $this->getShippingAmount());
        $order->setBaseShippingInvoiced($order->getBaseShippingInvoiced() + $this->getBaseShippingAmount());

        $order->setDiscountInvoiced($order->getDiscountInvoiced() + $this->getDiscountAmount());
        $order->setBaseDiscountInvoiced($order->getBaseDiscountInvoiced() + $this->getBaseDiscountAmount());
        $order->setBaseTotalInvoicedCost($order->getBaseTotalInvoicedCost() + $this->getBaseCost());

        $state = $this->getState();
        if (is_null($state)) {
            $this->setState(self::STATE_OPEN);
        }

        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_invoice_register', array($this->_eventObject=>$this, 'order' => $order));
        return $this;

    }

}
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. I thought that this is the right way.

Thank you.

Gr,
Lex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to rewrite do the following:

Adjust your module file to be reflect **WP_Sales**

Here is the way which it should work:

local/WP/Sales/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
       <models>
          <sales>
              <rewrite>
                  <order_invoice>WP_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice</order_invoice>
              </rewrite>
          </sales>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

local/WP/Sales/Model/Invoice.php

```
<?php
class WP_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice
{

    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->getId()) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cannot register existing invoice'));
        }

        foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getQty()>0) {
                $quantity = $item->getQty(); 
                $product_id = $item->getProductId();
                $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product_id);
                $stock->setQty($stock->getQty()-$quantity);           
                $stock->save();
                $item->register();
            }
            else {
                $item->isDeleted(true);
            }
        }

        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $captureCase = $this->getRequestedCaptureCase();
        if ($this->canCapture()) {
            if ($captureCase) {
                if ($captureCase == self::CAPTURE_ONLINE) {
                    $this->capture();
                }
                elseif ($captureCase == self::CAPTURE_OFFLINE) {
                    $this->setCanVoidFlag(false);
                    $this->pay();
                }
            }
        } elseif(!$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->isGateway() || $captureCase == self::CAPTURE_OFFLINE) {
            if (!$order->getPayment()->getIsTransactionPending()) {
                $this->setCanVoidFlag(false);
                $this->pay();
            }
        }

        $order->setTotalInvoiced($order->getTotalInvoiced() + $this->getGrandTotal());
        $order->setBaseTotalInvoiced($order->getBaseTotalInvoiced() + $this->getBaseGrandTotal());

        $order->setSubtotalInvoiced($order->getSubtotalInvoiced() + $this->getSubtotal());
        $order->setBaseSubtotalInvoiced($order->getBaseSubtotalInvoiced() + $this->getBaseSubtotal());

        $order->setTaxInvoiced($order->getTaxInvoiced() + $this->getTaxAmount());
        $order->setBaseTaxInvoiced($order->getBaseTaxInvoiced() + $this->getBaseTaxAmount());

        $order->setHiddenTaxInvoiced($order->getHiddenTaxInvoiced() + $this->getHiddenTaxAmount());
        $order->setBaseHiddenTaxInvoiced($order->getBaseHiddenTaxInvoiced() + $this->getBaseHiddenTaxAmount());

        $order->setShippingTaxInvoiced($order->getShippingTaxInvoiced() + $this->getShippingTaxAmount());
        $order->setBaseShippingTaxInvoiced($order->getBaseShippingTaxInvoiced() + $this->getBaseShippingTaxAmount());


        $order->setShippingInvoiced($order->getShippingInvoiced() + $this->getShippingAmount());
        $order->setBaseShippingInvoiced($order->getBaseShippingInvoiced() + $this->getBaseShippingAmount());

        $order->setDiscountInvoiced($order->getDiscountInvoiced() + $this->getDiscountAmount());
        $order->setBaseDiscountInvoiced($order->getBaseDiscountInvoiced() + $this->getBaseDiscountAmount());
        $order->setBaseTotalInvoicedCost($order->getBaseTotalInvoicedCost() + $this->getBaseCost());

        $state = $this->getState();
        if (is_null($state)) {
            $this->setState(self::STATE_OPEN);
        }

        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_invoice_register', array($this->_eventObject=>$this, 'order' => $order));
        return $this;

    }

}
```